# QT Creator defining exceptions

Tags: c++, qt, exception, qt-creator

I want to define a simple exception but when I do this Im getting an error saying "expected class name"

```
#include <exception>
class MyException : public exception{
    
};
```

This is in a QT (https://www.qt.io/) widget application.
Wont let me inherit from exception, why is this?

Comment: Maybe it should be `std::exception` instead?

Comment: @vahancho yup that was it thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <exception>

class MyException : public std::exception{
    
};
```